# How to save users logins count in database on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I was instructed to design a form which users are to login using their usernames and a specific PIN or PASSWORD given to them.

Each PASSWORD usage is counted and its usage limits is 5 times, after 3 times  the PASSWORD or PIN is the deleted from the database automatically.
I also have come to understand about stored procedures.
Please help me check if its correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].PinValidation
@Pin_no varchar(24),
@Reg_Num varchar(24),
@Session varchar(50),
@Tries INT,
@Program varchar(50)
AS
begin
SELECT Pin_no FROM PIN
WHERE Pin_no=@Pin_no
if @Reg_Num is not Null
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Reg_Num FROM PIN WHERE Reg_Num=@Reg_Num)
BEGIN
UPDATE PIN
SET Tries= Tries+1
WHERE Reg_Num=@Reg_Num--incrases the value of tries by 1 each time pin is used
SELECT @Tries[Tries]
end
ELSE
UPDATE PIN
SET Reg_num = @Reg_Num, P_Session=@Session, Tries=Tries+1, Program=@Program
Where Pin_no=@Pin_no --Updates database pin value for used pin on first usage
 end
 end
 If @Tries is not Null 
 BEGIN
if NOT EXISTS (SELECT Pin_no FROM PIN WHERE Pin_no=@Pin_no)
 BEGIN
 DELETE FROM [PIN ]
 WHERE  (( [Tries] = 3))--Check the Amount of times pin has been used if >3 delete entire pin row
 end
 end
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 SELECT -1
 END
```

Comment: Is there actually a question here? That sounds like a strange business rule to say the least. What part(s) do you need help with. As posted this is more like a consulting job than a little help in an online forum.

Comment: MARC.  I need help understanding how to implement this (question asked) into a login form.

Comment: Again...what part(s) do you need help with. There is the dotnet code, the sql code, the sql tables....

Comment: Sean tnks. i would luv d SQL and dotnet code.

Comment: SEAN. also i would also like you to give me a functional code that would help solve the problem in ASP.net

Comment: So let's see....you would like me to write the entire project for you free of charge so you can get paid. That is not going to happen. Good luck finding somebody to do your job for you.

Comment: SEAN !..... u making it now heavier for me.

Comment: SEAN ! if so i would luv you to but am a student.

Comment: SAEN.... how much would it cost to do that am in Nigeria.

Comment: and am designing using visual basic

Answer (score 0):

Insted of storing the pin or pw as a **String** or int store it as an **object** that has 2 proporties

```
public class pin {

    private int tries;
    private string pin;

}
```

then everytime after you find that the pin they have entered matches the one in the DB you add 1 to the pin.tries and check if it is equal to 5 or grater if so remove it from the DB.

Comment: thanks Donat.Am still a novince. i hope you can give me a code instance in other for me to understand better

Comment: are you familiar with "object oriented programming"? it is a really important aspect of programing it is recommended to use objects for a lot of things in languages that support OOP. if you are familiar with OOP i think you should give it s ahot and see if you can make it work if you are absolutly new to the concept of objects, you should read about it and if you are really stuck send me the part of your code where you check the validity of the pin and I will try to help you. :)

Comment: Donat tnks once again...i have been able to discover STORED PROCEDURE and it advantages.

Comment: help me check if this procedure can check and validate PIN:

Comment: @ONPOINT have you tried googling `object oriented programming` ? you can add methodes (functions) into objects for instance you can have a `public bool validatePin()` that function can return true if the pin is valid and false if it isn't **(you will still have to write the function yourself)** then you can use it in your code to find if a pin is valid